Multivariate chain rule (again) for differential forms
I know there has been many questions on multivariate chain rules already, but I read through a few of them and I'm still confused how to correctly do my case, so I will ask again.
I'm trying to prove that for an exact $1$-form $\alpha = \sum_i f_i dx_i$, the $0$-form $g(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_j x_j\left(\int_0^1 f_j(t\mathbf{x})dt\right)$ is an antiderivative i.e. $dg = \alpha$.
By definition, it suffices to prove that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} = f_i$. So I get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}
&= \left(\int_0^1 f_i(t\mathbf{x})dt\right) + \left(\sum_j x_j \left(\int_0^1 \frac{\partial(f_j(t\mathbf{x}))}{\partial x_i} \right)\right) \\
&= \left(\int_0^1 f_i(t\mathbf{x})dt\right) + \left(\sum_j x_j \left(\int_0^1 \color{red}{\sum_k \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_k} \cdot \frac{\partial (tx_k)}{\partial x_i} } \right)\right) \\
&= \int_0^1 f_i(t\mathbf{x})dt + \sum_j x_j \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}(t\mathbf{x}) \cdot tdt
\end{align*}
First question is whether the chain rule application at the red part is correct. The second question is how do I proceed from here?

Numerical example I worked through: take $\alpha = x^2y dx + x dy$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
&= \int_0^1 (x^2y)\big|_{x=tx,y=ty} dt + x\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\partial(x^2y)}{\partial x}\right)\big|_{x=tx,y=ty} \cdot tdt + y\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\partial(x^2y)}{\partial y}\right)\big|_{x=tx,y=ty} \cdot tdt \\
&= \int_0^1 t^3x^2y dt + x \int_0^1 (2t^2xy) \cdot tdt + y \int_0^1 (t^2x^2) \cdot tdt
\end{align*}
But I don't get much insight on how to simplify this in general. I guess when $f_i$ is polynomial this is easier but about in general..

Somehow I have figured it out only 15 minutes after asking the question, despite spending an hour on it before asking. The main observation is that
$$
\sum_i \int \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(t\mathbf{x}) \cdot x_j dt = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(f_i(t\mathbf{x})\right)
$$
The proof being using the chain rule on the right hand side. However, this is not sufficient. If you look closely above, we actually have $\partial f_j / \partial x_i$ instead of $\partial f_i / \partial x_j$. However, they are equal for exact $1$-forms, since $0 = d\alpha = \sum_i df_i dx_i = \sum_i \sum_j (\partial f_i / \partial x_j) dx_j dx_i$, and using $dx_idx_j = -dx_jdx_i$ and looking at its coefficient shows it. Finally, apply integration by parts.
Alternate proof for the reciprocity law (?) is that $\alpha = d\beta$, so $f_i$ is just $\partial \beta / \partial x_i$ and $\partial f_i / \partial x_j = \partial^2 \beta / \partial x_i \partial x_j$, and use smoothness.

Congratulations on answering your own question. It's happened to me often that once I spend the time to write up the question, the answer (or something I hadn't thought of that leads to the answer) pops into my head. I think it's one reason why Q&A sites demand users do the work it takes to ask a good question.
